# Is there a way to place a symbolic link in Volumes on Mac that won't be deleted when the machine reboots?

Tags: mac, symbolic-link, dropbox

I use Dropbox in a newspaper publishing environment.

While in the office I mount a share from my Synology NAS that shares my Dropbox content via CloudSync.

For a remote computer, I use the Mac Dropbox app. However, I need the path to the Dropbox folder to emulate the office behavior - i.e., /Volumes/Dropbox

I can get that to work by creating a symbolic link in /Volumes, named Dropbox, that points to the Dropbox folder in my home directory (the default location the Dropbox app now uses on Macs).

However, when I reboot the computer, the symbolic link disappears. Is there a way to place a symbolic link on Mac that won't be delete when the machine reboots?

Or, in lieu of that, would there be a way to have a startup script that creates that symlink on login?

Comment: Never tried it for this scenario, but for regular drives you want back on the desktop persistently use a regular old fashioned alias. They're permanent. Might be worth a shot…